# css column count ignored on IE11

Tags: html, css, column-count

This is a issue I have on my site, I have recreated the problem on js fiddle, I am trying to create 5 columns using section tags with an even width using column count, this works fine on chrome/firefox/edge, however on Internet explorer 11 it is ignored and displays the sections as blocks.

I read that column count should be supported by IE so it's very confusing as to why it is being ignored, is this a bug or am i doing something wrong?
my fiddle is below

https://jsfiddle.net/gqdL46j4/

html

```
<main>
  <section>
    <h1>Test1</h1>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h1>Test2</h1>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h1>Test3</h1>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h1>Test4</h1>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h1>Test5</h1>
  </section>
</main>
```

css

```
main  {
   -webkit-column-count: 5;
   -moz-column-count: 5; 
   column-count: 5;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<main>` tag is not supported by IE. It only is supported by Firefox + Chrome + Edge:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main

That's the reason why it doesn't work with columns.

Comment: Thanks for that, I had no idea

Answer (score 0):

I just tried replacing the main tag with a div and it works now, is there a reason why it wouldn't work with the main tag?

https://jsfiddle.net/gqdL46j4/3/

```
<div>
  <section>
    <h1>Test1</h1>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h1>Test2</h1>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h1>Test3</h1>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h1>Test4</h1>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h1>Test5</h1>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Good find! Apparently, IE11 still doesn't know about `<main>`. See also [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main). The problem in the original snippet would also be solved by giving `main` an explicit `display:block`. ([New fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gqdL46j4/4/).) The issue being that unknown elements are treated as inline, and inline elements can't contain columns.

Comment: Thanks for that, I had no idea, also the display:block is a good tip, cheers